# Cannot set property 'src' of null Angular - Typescript error

Tags: angular, image-upload

I am trying to get the image from computer, and trying to set this image into an image element, but I get the following error.

> Cannot set property 'src' of null

Can anybody help?

**This is my component file code.**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
    title = 'app';
    event: any;
    url: any;
    onSelectFile = (event) => { // called each time file input changes
        if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]); // read file as data url
            reader.onload = (event: any) => {
                this.url = event.result;
                console.log(this.url);
                var image = document.getElementById("#image") as HTMLImageElement;
                image.src = this.url;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**this is my HTML file code.**

```
<img id="image"  height="200"> <br/>    
<input type='file' (change)="onSelectFile($event)">
```

Whenever I set the value of my image element I get the error mentioned above.

Comment: Remove the `#` from your selector. Should just be `document.getElementById("image")`

Comment: Why would you even use document.getElementById here? The whole point of Angular is that it gives you better tools to do it.

Comment: this line `onSelectFile = (event) => {` could be just changed to `onSelectFile(event) {`...

Answer (score 2):

Databind the src attribute of the image to the url property:

```
<img id="image" height="200" [src]="url">
```

Remove all the code after assigning the image link to the url property.

```
export class AppComponent {
    title = 'app';
    event: any;
    url = '';

    onSelectFile = (event) => { // called each time file input changes
        if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]); // read file as data url
            reader.onload = (event: any) => {
                this.url = event.result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the  id is "image", without "#", because you are using getElementById method.